# I can't open blue ocean pipeline editor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I installed Blue Ocean in Jenkins. I can create pipeline from Blue Ocean but I can't edit pipeline.

It stuck at "Connect to Git"

[image]

In dev console,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 428 (Precondition Required)
```

How can I connect to git to open pipeline editor from Blue Ocean?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this issue, you need to add "Check out to matching local branch" to your branch source --> behaviour in your pipeline.

[EXAMPLE:"Check out to matching local branch"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XQw6.png)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that when I created the git credentials, it looked like it was happy and worked.  However, the button did not change to a "check-mark"; as it turns out, I using my new SSO enterprise credentials, but Bitbucket credentials used my old SSO enterprise credentials.  When I added new credentials, with the old password it worked and the Editor opened.

Also note: I did check if I had the "Check out to match local branch" behavior configured in the pipeline setup -- I did, therefore, that was not contributing to my error.